# make combobox availabe in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Im having a combobox in xaml file.
by passing datacontext to my viewmodel file.
I want to add the combobox context from my view model file.
How can i achieve this , via **mvvm pattern**

**xaml code**:

```
<ComboBox   Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="SelectNameCB"  
            FontSize="15" 
            Margin="10,0,0,0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="207" />
```

In viewmodel file, SelectNameCB states that its not available in current context.
**viewmodel file**

```
private void ComboBoxdata()
{
    OleDbConnection ConDb;
    String eID;

    ConDb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Feedback\\Feedback.accdb");

    try
    {
        ConDb.Open();
        OleDbCommand DBSelect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select FName, LName,ID_NAME from NameList", ConDb);
        OleDbDataReader reader = DBSelect.ExecuteReader();



        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string eNAME = "";
            eID = reader["ID_NAME"].ToString();

            eNAME += reader["FName"].ToString();
            eNAME += " " + reader["LName"].ToString();

            SelectNameCB.Items.Add(eNAME);


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ae)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ae.Message);

    }//catch
}
```

Comment: With question stated this way you can safely remove 'MVVM' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private List<string> _MyComboBoxData;
public List<string> MyComboBoxData
{
    get
    {
        return _MyComboBoxData;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyComboBoxData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => MyComboBoxData);
    }
}
```

and this too:

```
ConDb.Open();
OleDbCommand DBSelect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select FName, LName,ID_NAME from NameList", ConDb);
OleDbDataReader reader = DBSelect.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string eNAME = "";
    eID = reader["ID_NAME"].ToString();
    eNAME += reader["FName"].ToString();
    eNAME += " " + reader["LName"].ToString();

    MyComboBoxData.Add(eNAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you have to read more about the MVVM pattern. The ViewModel should not know anything about the View (where the ComboBox resides).

The DataContext of the view is set to the ViewModel not the other way around.

```
view.DataContext = viewModel
```

If you want to fill a combobox with values add a property to the viewModel

```
public ObervableCollection<string> Values {get; set;}
```

Then bind the comboboxes ItemsSource to the Values property

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Also add a MySelectedItem poperty to the ViewModel to get the selected value. (You may also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your ViewModel)

```
public string SelectedItem {get; set;}
```

Now if you set the Values property in the ViewModel the Combobox will get your list of data. First of all fill a List from your reader and then use it as a parameter to the ObservableCollection constructor.

```
Values = new ObervableCollection<string>(listOfeNAME);
```